# A Python Inheritance Problem: TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not None

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I want to save the class name and class itself into a python dict by using a decorator.

```py
from functools import wraps
models = {} # python dict which save class name and class

def register_model(name):
    def register(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(name):
            models[name] = func

        return inner(name)

    return register

# `A` is a class that I want to save into the dict.

@register_model('1244')
class A(object):
    a = 1

    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()

# But when call it below:

print(models['1244']().a)
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Data/Usr/t.py", line 50, in <module>
    print(models['1244']().a)
  File "/Data/Usr/t.py", line 36, in __init__
    super(A, self).__init__()
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not None
```

I solve this error by changing `super(A, self).__init__()` to `super().__init__()`

I want to know why augment 1 is None and what cause it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decorator doesn't return anything, and whatever it returns will be assigned to the name `A` (the class definition). You're making the class accessible solely through `models['1244']`, `A()` as such doesn't work (because `A` is `None`). This is what's happening when you do `super(A, ...)`.

1. You don't need to pass `A` to `super`, just `super().__init__()` will do just fine. This would resolve this particular problem.
2. Your decorator should return the class.

In fact, your decorator is overly complicated. `inner` is completely superfluous. Change it to this to solve both issues:

```
def register_model(name):
    def register(cls):
        models[name] = cls
        return cls

    return register
```

Now it just registers the class in `models` and otherwise lets it pass through unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Your decorator returns `None`, so `A` in the original scope ends up being `None`, and `super(A, self)` with `A = None` is an invalid call. The simple fix is to `return func` from the decorator.

Simplifying your code and getting rid of outdated idioms such as inheriting from `object` and `super(..., ...)`, things work fine:

```
models = {}


def register_model(name):
    def register(cls):
        models[name] = cls
        return cls

    return register


@register_model('1244')
class A:
    a = 1

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Hi!")


print(models['1244']().a)
```